# How to compare two dates in MS Dynamics AX 2009?

Tags: date, compare, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

How to compare two dates (instances of type Date, not utcDateTime) in MS Dynamics AX 2009?

I want to check if particular date, taken from the table, is before (or after) the another one. Both are date types.

Is there a way to convert date to utcDateTime datatype?

Comment: "from the table"? Compare 2 dates in the same table or in two different tables. If needed copy your query to the question.

Comment: If you find an answer useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to compare two dates?

Use the comparison operators `<` `<=` `>=` `>` `==` and `!=`.

```
if (LedgerTrans.TransDate > systemDateGet() - 3)
    LedgerTrans.TransDate = systemDateGet() - 3;
```

This works in selects too:

```
select firstonly LedgerTrans 
    where LedgerTrans.TransDate > systemDateGet() - 3;
```

It works in query input ranges as well: `>13-08` will select select dates after August 13'th of the current year.
See also: http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2010/02/utcdatetime-in-dynamics-ax-2009.html

How to convert a date to `utcDateTime`?

```
DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(systemDateGet(), 0, DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone()));
```

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc584924.aspx

There is no need to convert `Date` to `utcDateTime` to compare two dates.